# bind click events to dynamic buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I'm trying to make the click event work for a list of dynamically added buttons.

See this jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jeffxiao/u1dc57za/5/

the failing line is:

```
$(".run").on('click', 'ul#mitigationList', clickFunction);
```

Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: `$("ul#mitigationList").on('click', '.run', clickFunction);` and `$("ul#mitigationList").on('click', '.run', function(e){`

Comment: i just realize the failing line should be as above. working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jeffxiao/u1dc57za/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is that `$('.run').on('click', 'ul#mitigationList', clickFunction)` will look for clicks on `ul#mitigationList` descendants of `.run` elements which isn't what you want.

Think of it like this:

```
$('elementsToWatch').on('eventName', 'descendants', functionToRun)
```

Have updated your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/u1dc57za/11/

Answer (score 1):

**Use this click event code :**

```
$(document).on("click", ".run", function(){
alert("Clicked!");
});
```

Working jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rajnikpatel/76nmazcf/

Comment: `$("ul#mitigationList").on('click', '.run', clickFunction);` works as well

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1207393/3380951) mentions the correct syntax: `$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $("html body").on('click', '.run', clickFunction);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u1dc57za/12/